# Hibernate 4 Criteria query returns empty list

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring 4 and Hibernate 4 but the query always returns empty list even through there should be few rows.

This is the model

```
@DynamicUpdate 
@Table(appliesTo = "comments")
public class Comment {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

... and some getters and setters ...
```

This is the Spring configuration part

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://mydbroot/circle" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="user" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="password" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</beans:bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="commentDao"
    class="com.hersbitcloud.cancercloud.models.circle.CommentDAO">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

The hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
</session-factory>
```

For the DAO

```
public class CommentDAO {

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public CommentDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@Transactional
public List<Comment> GetComments() {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Comment> listComment = (List<Comment>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createCriteria(Comment.class).list();

    return listComment;
}
```

}

In my controller

```
    @Autowired
private CommentDAO commentDao;

@RequestMapping(value = "/comment", method = RequestMethod.GET) //, produces="application/json")
public int comment() {

    List<Comment> listComments = commentDao.GetComments();
    return listComments.size();

}
```

It always shows `listComments.size()` is 0.

What's the problem?

I attach screenshot of the database to show that table name is correct.
[image]

Comment: arent you missing the "@Entity" annotation? And why is the "@Id" commented out?

Comment: Either you forgot to commit the transaction which inserted the rows, or you're not getting the comments from the right database/schema/table.

Comment: enable query logs by enabling show sql to true and see what queries are fired to db

Comment: @JBNizet I'm quite sure the table is correct because I have another servlet using JDBC that works fine. What you mean 'commit the transaction which inserted the rows'? Actually the rows were inserted by using JDBC servlet without transaction.

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Actually "@Entity" is deprecated since Hibernate 4.0+. I uncomment "@id" but the problem still exist.

Comment: @Steven Luo I meant the JPA annotation " @javax.persistence.Entity"

Comment: Where is your mappings for annotated class (Entity)? Sadly, Hibernate does not Scan for annotated classes at startup and so you have to configure Hibernate manually, either through an XML configuration file or Programmatically, so that it knows about your annotated classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RaphaelRoth Thank you for your reply. I got everything to work by changing

```
@DynamicUpdate 
@Table(appliesTo = "comments")
```

Into

```
@Entity
@Table(name="comments")
```

both of them belongs to 'javax.persistence.*'.

Comment: What if I have dynamic-update="true" in my mapping file. I am not using annotations in my case but have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these lines in your class `CommentDAO` changing this:

```
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

To:

```
        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }
```

Comment: @Steven Luo are you sure your db connection are ok

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Actually if I change any connection information, other exceptions are thrown. I also attached a screenshot of navicat.

Answer (score 0):

I think `@Transactional` is used perform modification process on DB. Remove the `@Transactional` and Give it a try,

```
public List<Comment> GetComments() {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Comment> listComment = (List<Comment>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createCriteria(Comment.class).list();

return listComment;
}
```

Give `@Transactional` above class.

If you want to do perform action db, give `@Transactional(readOnly=false)`

Comment: Removing '@Transactional' throws the exception that session can not be obtained. Putting '@Transactional' above class does not solve the problem.

Comment: add  @Transactional on your service class, here I think you are using controller only.. mark it on 
`@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "/comment", method = RequestMethod.GET) //, produces="application/json")
public int comment() {

    List<Comment> listComments = commentDao.GetComments();
    return listComments.size();

}`